# What is element.style and why is it overriding my css settings?

Tags: css

I have a popup that comes up over a blanket div that greys out the entire screen, but I don't like its positioning.  So I tried to manually enter `left:` and `top:` elements into my CSS, but when I look at Chrome's console, there's this `element.style {}` that's overriding my code.

I've searched my CSS file for `element.style` and for `597px` and `794px` and I don't get hits on any of them.

What is this, and why does it have the values that it has?

[image]

Answer (score 22):

`element.style` is a part of your browser devtools that indicates the inline style of the element which has a higher [specificity value](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity) than any CSS selectors.

That inline styles may be added by a JavaScript code, if so, you can override that declarations by using `!important` keyword within your stylesheet (e.g. `left: 610px !important`).

Comment: awesome.  That makes sense. I'd bet there's some JavaScript that's causing it.

Answer (score 11):

**element.style** refers to inline styles on the dom element. For example:

```
<p style="color:#cc0000;">Foo</p>
```

the color of that paragraph would show up under **element.style**.

You can fix with your css by doing this:

```
#popUpDiv[style]{
    left:610px !important;
    top:0px !important;
}
```

HTH
-Ted

Answer (score 2):

That's probably manipulated and set by javascript (either that or you edited the element.style{} rule yourselves on the developer tools console).

Look for javascript code that changes the display, top and left properties of #popupDiv

Answer (score 1):

It is the style that you have in the HTML file.
try to delete or change the style in HTML.