# jQuery UI Auto Complete wrap results

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui-autocomplete

When using autocomplete with narrow screens, the results end up in a window that you need to scroll right and left to see them. I added a `max-width` to `.ui-autocomplete.ui-menu` and set a smaller font and now the results are only as wide as the screen, but does not wrap and the information to the right is hidden. I set `.ui-menu-item` to wrap, but in chrome developer tools, when I look at the element style, under `element.style` it still says nowrap and my entry is marked out. I am not sure what `element.style` is or how to override it. I tried the `!important` flag, but that did not help. Any suggestions on either how to override that style or a better way of making the results wrap?

Ok, here is more:
I am using the default jQuery UI JS and CSS.  I added:
this CSS at the end of my head:

```css
.ui-autocomplete.ui-menu{
 max-width:90%;
 }

 .ui-menu-item{
  white-space:wrap!important;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: break-all;
  }
```

Here is the dev console css info:
[image: Dev console css]

Comment: It would help here if we actually had some HTML and CSS from your code to work with, otherwise we are guessing and likely less than optimal. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Anytime you use `!important` it is likely somehthing is wrong

Comment: Where does "element.style" come from and how to I override it?

Comment: element.style shows any inline styles on that inspected element. Inline styles override CSS. More here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28353386/what-is-element-style-and-why-is-it-overriding-my-css-settings/28353450#:~:targetText=element.,override%20that%20declarations%20by%20using%20!

Comment: This might give you some place to work from https://stackoverflow.com/a/28286277/125981

Comment: The style basic https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/themes/base/autocomplete.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must normal instead wrap.

white-space: normal !important;

Comment: Thanks!  I can't believe I missed normal instead of wrap.  Must have looked at it too long.