# css style is getting overwritten by element.style

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, slider

I have an image slideshow with arrow buttons (CSS style slidePrev and slideNext). However, I cannot get the buttons to show up halfway down the images, rather they show up at the top.

Here's the CSS code that should work

```
#fwslider .slideNext {
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    right:-50px;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

However, this style is somehow getting overwritten by something called element.style (which may come from Bootstrap?).  Chrome gives no clue as to where the source is:

[image: From Chrome's F12]

Does anyone know what is overwriting my style? I don't even know how to go about debugging this so any tips appreciated.

Comment: element.style should be hardcoded style inside the html of the page, surely in the inspected element. Check its content in the html source. Look for something like `style="right: 0px; top:-52px;opacity:0.5"` in it.

Comment: If everything else fails you can try to overwrite it with !important. top:50% !important;
    right:-50px !important;

Answer (score 2):

About your question: **Does anyone know what is overwriting my style?** the answer is the `element.style`... but what is the ***element.style***?

As said in this other SO question: [What is element.style and why is it overriding my css settings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28353386/what-is-element-style-and-why-is-it-overriding-my-css-settings)

> element.style refers to inline styles on the dom element.

In your case, **element.style** should be a hardcoded style inside the html of the page, surely in the *button* element. ***Check its content in the html source*** and look for something like this:

```
<button class="slideNext" style="right: 0px; top:-52px;opacity:0.5">
```

Once found, you can delete, add or modify its content as you wish.

Additionaly, you could edit the CSS external style in **fwslider.css** file and add the `!important` rule to affected styles *forcing them to override current inline style behaviour*, but it is prefered to avoid to use `style=` inside inline document elements, to avoid this kind of missunderstandings and to separate structure (html) from layout (styles).

About **order precedences** when adding styles check [What is the order of precedence for CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25105736/what-is-the-order-of-precedence-for-css), where its saids:

> There are several rules ( applied in this order ) :
>
> 1. inline css ( html style attribute ) overrides css rules in style tag and css file
> 2. a more specific selector takes precedence over a less specific one
> 3. rules that appear later in the code override earlier rules if both have the same specificity.
> 4. A css rule with !important always takes precedence.

### Important

These rules also applies for **`!important`** rule, so its precedence priority is also in that order too.

---

### Update: What happens if javascript manages css properties?

Using **jquery** or **vanilla javascript** to manage css properties causes the addition, modification or deletion of `element.style` properties.  So it affects the way that the *browser* see it and that changes will appear in its *inspector* inside the `element.style`.

By instance: If we execute this *jquery function*:

```
$('#fwslider).css('top','-52px');
```

it will add or modify the current value of the attribute `style=` inside the `#fwslider` element.

***Before the execution of javascript code:***
[image]

***After the execution of javascript code:***
[image]

So, take in consideration that ***if you are not finding a specific css property in your html code files*** but it appears inside the  `element.style` in your browser inspector, then ***it could be generated by javascript code***.

Comment: Thank you for explaining what's going on, I now understand what the generic element.style means. I searched the entire code block for -52 and not surprisingly didn't find it.  I believe it's getting dynamically set by some Javascript during the slideshow.  Using !important helps, but I still have problems as I'll outline in another response.  Many thanks for the help and explanation.

Comment: Update: The problem I was going to outline was caused by a missing first image in the slideshow.  Not sure why it was causing problems, but instead of tracking it down a "what if" I'll just make sure the images are all there with alt tags so I can easily see it's missing

Comment: @SteveSilberberg: I have updated my answer adding new explanation about javascript behaviour over css styles inline (as it seems your case).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `!important` in CSS to overwrite the default style. [Check out the rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70408430/font-size-does-not-work-properly-on-phoenix-browser/70408871#70408871) for your CSS

The code can be :

```
#fwslider .slideNext {
    position: absolute;
    top:50% !important;
    right:-50px !important;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Comment: Despite it could solve his current problem, this is not answering the question he wanted to understand and asked for: **Does anyone know what is overwriting my style?**  I have added a new answer with expanded information.  Also see my comment in initial question comments.