# font size does not work properly on Phoenix browser

Tags: html, css, web, fonts, typography

I designed a webpage, and have used all kinds of units for font size, but Phoenix browser app seems to have a setting, how can I override it in css

Answer (score -1):

You can use `!important`  in CSS to overwrite the default style. [Check out the  rule](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_important.asp) for your CSS

Comment: still doesn't work, 30px or 2.5vw for example is clear on chrome and opera but so thin on Phoenix